# How to get Content-Type when uploading file from flash - is it possible?

Tags: html, flash

we have a small flash component on our website/application to upload multiple files.
This works fine, however we want to get the Content-Type from the headers and its always set to 'application/octet-stream'. From what I've learned this is due to a security of flash sandbox and FileUpLoad will never give this to us.

Is there any other way we could do this in flash (aside from creating an html/ajax multi file upload)?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had a simlar problem when uploading from a browser. What is sent in the content type is dependent upon the browser **and** what is installed on the client machine. If it is an extension that the client machine does not recognise it will come back as application/octet-stream.

What we ended up doing was creating mapping functionality from the file extension to the content type. That way we could ensure consistency.

Comment: yeah thats what we are doing now, but it not 100% reliable.
thanks for your answer though.